# Node.js : multiple callbacks from one function

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I've run into a problem in my application's code and I would like to know the best way to handle it: I have a function that applies 5 values on callback and I would like to know the best way to use it.

Here is my function code :

```
var someFunc = function(callback) {
var http = require('http');
var id;
var url = 'http://somesite.com/json';


// First request to get an array of 5 elements
http.get(url, function(res) {
    var body = '';

    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        body += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function() {
        var jsonResult = JSON.parse(body);
// 5 requests with a value from each of the 5 elements
        for (var i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            (function(idx) {
                gameId = jsonResult.gameList[idx].id;
                url = 'http://somesite.com' + id + '/token';
                http.get(url, function(res) {
                    var body = '';

                    res.on('data', function(chunk) {
                        body += chunk;
                    });

                    res.on('end', function() {
                        jsonRes = JSON.parse(body);
                        callback.apply(null, [idx, jsonRes.interestScore]);
                    });
                }).on('error', function(e) {
                    console.log("Got error: ", e);
                });
            })(i);
        }

    });
}).on('error', function(e) {
    console.log("Got error: ", e);
});
};
exports.someFunc = someFunc;
```

When I call the function to retrieve the 5 values I do it like this :

```
exports.featured = function(req, res){
    getSome.someFunc(function callback(result) {
        var variables = {};
        var variableName = result;
        variables[variableName] = jsonRes.interestScore;
        res.render('featured', { score0: variables[0], score1: variables[1], score2: variables[2], score3: variables[3], score4: variables[4] });
    });
};
```

Unfortunately 'res.render' is called after the function retrieved only 1 value, so I want to know how to do it proprely, or make a proper callback.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem which I'm seeing is that you are assigning listener for the *end* event five times. You should do that only once. You can collect the result five times and after that call the callback. Here is an example which uses request module:

```
var request = require('request');

var makeRequests = function(callback) {
    var result = [],
        done = 0;
    request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            // read the body here
            var searchFor = [
                'nodejs',       // 1
                'http request', // 2
                'npm',          // 3
                'express',      // 4
                'javascript'    // 5
            ];
            for(var i=0; keyword = searchFor[i]; i++) {
                request('https://www.google.bg/search?q=' + keyword, function (error, response, body) {
                    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                        result.push(body);
                        ++done;
                        if(done == searchFor.length) {
                            callback(result);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}

makeRequests(function(result) {
    console.log("result=" + result.length);
})
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to mention that the loop was important in my code, it is used to make a http get request. I'll edit my post with the full function code to be clearer.

Comment: Ok, I understand but attaching a listener inside a loop is not a good idea. It will lead to unexpected results, because you have a lot of functions called on that *end* event

Comment: Yes I understand, that is what I was trying to avoid, and why I asked here.

Comment: Would it still be possible to rearrange my code without removing the loop or do I need to re-write it?

Comment: Hm ... I don't get it. According this http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback the http.get method is written to host get request without bodies. But you need the body, so I guess it will be easier for you to use http.request. Besides that I'll suggest to rewrite your code. As I said attaching listeners to same events multiple times is not a good idea. You have a listener of http.get and inside it you have another one again of http.get. It will be good if you share your main goal. Is that you want to get the first five chunks of the a get request?

Comment: The first call that I do returns 5 values, I use these values to make 5 other different calls, and each of these calls get me the value I'm looking for.

Comment: I edited my answer. It contains a working script which makes one get request and when it finishes it makes five others, waits for their results and call the callback at the end. You should add *"request": "*"* in your package.json file.

Answer (score 1):

The function you call is async, response `end` events can be happening anytime. And your code causes `res.render` to execute 5 times, but you only need it to execute 1 time with 5 values. You should be using a module like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) which will help you to fire multiple tasks, and callback when all of them is finished.

Example:

```
var jsonResult = JSON.parse(body);
var arr = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
   arr.push(jsonResult[0].interestScore);
}
async.map(arr, myAsyncFunction, function(err, results){
   // results[0] => response of first index
   // results[4] => response of last index
});
```